# Ajax-PhP communication

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a problem with a script i am programming. I am very new to AJAX, and can't figure out what i am doing wrong that makes it not to work. Any help would be highly appreciated. I have multiple forms on the page and when i separate the forms the communication between the Ajax and php works just fine. But when i put everything together, it stops working. I do believe its either a communication problem or maybe some conflicting scripts or just some bad coding.

Here is the php code:

```
@session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
   header("location: home.php");
exit();
}else{
    $usertitle = $_POST['ut'];
    $userfname = $_POST['uf'];
    $userlname = $_POST['ul'];
    $useremail = $_POST['ue'];
    $userloc = $_POST['uloc'];
    $user_est_typ = $_POST['utp'];
    $userfname = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?![:space:]]/","",$userfname);
    $userlname = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?![:space:]]/","",$userlname);
    if($usertitle == "Title...."){
        echo '<font color="red">Error: Please select a title.';
        exit();
    }else if($userfname == NULL){
        exit('<font color="red">Error:  You need a first name to proceed. </font>');
    }else if( strlen($userfname) <= 2){
        exit('<font color="red">Error: First name should be three (3) or more letters.</font>');
    } else if($userlname == ""){
        exit('<font color="red">Error: Giving a Surname would be nice.</font>');
    }else if( strlen($userlname) <= 2){
        exit('<font color="red">Error: Surname should be three (3) or more Letters.</font>');
    }else if(!strpos($useremail, "@") || !strpos($useremail, "." || !filter_var($useremail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === true)){
        exit('<font color="red">Email Address not valid</font>');
    }else if($user_est_typ == "Select..."){
        exit('<font color="red">Error: You must select an estimate type to proceed.</font>');
    }else if($userloc == ""){
        exit('<font color="red">Error: A location would be required so as to get the radiation data for the estimates</font>');
    }else {
        include("../../scripts/dbconect.php");
        $queryuseremail = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM userdata WHERE userEmail='$useremail' LIMIT 1"); 
        $useremail_check = mysql_num_rows($queryuseremail);
        if ($useremail_check > 0){ 
         echo "The email address ".$useremail." is already registered in ur database";
        exit();
        }
        // More Validation and mysql insert

        exit('<font color="red">signup_success</font>');
    }
}
```

Here is my AJAX codes:

```
  function _(x){
         return document.getElementById(x);
   }

   function show(id){
        var divelement = _(id);
        if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
           divelement.style.display = 'block';
           else
   divelement.style.display == 'none';
   }


   function hide(id){
      var divelement = _(id);
      if(divelement.style.display == 'block')
        divelement.style.display = 'none';
      else
        divelement.style.display == 'block';
   }

 function emptyElement(id){
    _(id).innerHTML = "";
 }

 function estimatetypeimg(){
      var estType = _('estimatetype').value;
       if (estType == 'solarpv'){
           show('estimate_pv'); 
           hide('estimate_thermal');
         }
          else if(estType == 'solarthermal'){
            hide('estimate_pv'); 
            show('estimate_thermal');
        }
       else{
         hide('estimate_pv'); 
         hide('estimate_thermal');
       }
     }

  function newUsers() {
     var title = _("salutation").value;
     var fname = _("fname").value;
     var lname = _("lname").value;
     var email = _("email").value;
     var loc = _("location").value;
     var tp = _("estimatetype").value;
     var url = "ajax.php";
     var vars = "ut="+title+"uf="+fname+"&ul="+lname+"&ue="+email+"&uloc="+loc+"&utp="+tp;

     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        _("statuscheck").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(vars);
  }
```

And here is my html code:

```
<div id="startbuts" style="display:none">
    <form class="pure-form" name="startbutsform" id="startbutsform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <button type="submit" id="newusersbtn" onclick="show('newusers'); hide('existingusers'); hide('existingusersbtn');"class="pure-button pure-button-primary">New Estimate</button>
        <button type="submit" id="existingusersbtn" onclick="show('existingusers'); hide('newusers'); hide('newusersbtn');" class="button-secondary pure-button">Load Previous Estimate</button>
    </form>

    <div id="existingusers" style="display:none">
        <form class="pure-form" name="signupex" id="signupex" onsubmit="return false;">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Existing users: login with your email and Data ID.</legend>
                    <input type="email" id="dataemail" placeholder="Email" >
                        <input type="text" id="dataid" placeholder="DataId"><br/>
                            <button id="signupexbtn" type="submit" onclick="signinold()" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Sign in</button>
                 </fieldset>
                 </form>
               </div>
              <div id="newusers" style="display:none">
             <form class="pure-form" name="signupnew" id="signupnew" onsubmit="return false;">
             <fieldset>
                    <legend>New users start here.</legend>
                      <div class="pure-control-group">
                      <label for="salutation">Title: </label>
                      <select id="salutation" name="salutation">
                      <option>Title....</option>
                      <option>Prof. Dr.</option>
                      <option>Prof.</option>
                      <option>Dr.</option>
                      <option>Mr.</option>
                      <option>Mrs.</option>
                      <option>Miss.</option>
               </select>
            </div>
           <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input id="lname" name="lname" onfocus="emptyElement('errorcheck')" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>

    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" onfocus="emptyElement('errorcheck')" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>

    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="location">Project Location: </label>
        <input id="location" name="location" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('errorcheck')" placeholder="Enter City ex Buea...">
    </div>

    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="estimatetype">Type of Estimate: </label>

        <select id="estimatetype" name="estimatetype" onchange="estimatetypeimg()">
            <option value="Select">Select...</option>
            <option value="solarpv">Solar PV</option>
            <option value="solarthermal">Solar Thermal</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="estimate_pv" style="display:none" >
        <img id="solarpvimg" src="images/solarpv.png" width="250" height="109" alt="Solar PV" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="estimate_thermal" style="display:none">
        <img  id="solarthermalimg" src="images/solarthermal.png" width="250" height="109" alt="Solar PV" /> 
    </div>
    <hr/>
        <button id="signupnewbtn" type="button" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" onclick="newUsers()" >Start Calculator</button>
        <button onclick="emptyElement('errorcheck'); hide('estimate_pv'); hide(estimate_thermal);" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" type="reset">Reset </button>
       </fieldset>
         </form>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Why dont you use one single form for everything instead?

Comment: Buddy, though it's too tiresome to understand the whole sequence of your code, I will suggest you use jquery and malsup jquery plugin for submitting  forms via ajax. Also improve the php script you are using, it can be minimized and can be made more readable

Comment: The reason is some of the forms are going to be displayed based on responses from the php script. So i don't know how its going to be like if i use one form for all. But will try that out

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David Lavieri and especially Sher Kahn. Your responses got me thinking and i finally figured out why I was not getting any response from my PhP script. As Khan also mention, I am just a hobby coder and you are absolutely right my code is not very clean.  I cleaned the code on JSLint and realised i had too many bad coding habits. :). Thanks also for giving me a heads up with malsup query plugins. they are very handy and will help a lot.

So finally to the problem I had. The actual problem was the link to the php file. The url was poorly defined which made it impossible for the communication between the ajax and the php file. I use Dreamweaver and when i used the browse tool it gave me a link to the file, but because my javascript was external, the link was only relative to the Javascript file, and not the main html file. Also when i double checked my data vars, i missed and "&" for my second variable in the string before "uf"

```
var url = "ajax.php";// i changed the path file to scripts/ajax.php and it worked like magic.
var vars = "ut="+title+"uf="+fname+"&ul="+lname+"&ue="+email+"&uloc="+loc+"&utp="+tp;// before
 var vars = "ut="+title+"&uf="+fname+"&ul="+lname+"&ue="+email+"&uloc="+loc+"&utp="+tp;// After
```

Hope this can be of help to someone else.

regards and thanks David and Khan.